# Solving the Error: INF WIS 10901 On Webi report?

Tags: business-intelligence, hana, business-objects, webi

I was working on an existing report in Webi to modify the query, and I have an error while refreshing it that states :

"***SQL statement is too long.. For information about this error, please refer to SAP Knowledge Base Article 2054721 on the SAP Support Portal. (IES 10901) (Error: INF WIS 10901)***"

Does anyone know what causes this issue ?

Thank you for your help !

I've tried deleting any prompts and deleting some variables